# My solution for IPO (Initial Public Offering) auction interview question

Tags: python

[image]

*TLDR:

Input:

bids = list of lists of ints representing [userid, # shares, $bid, timestamp]

totalShares = total # of shares to be distributed.

TODO: distribute shares amongst bidders and return userids of bidders that got 0 shares. Share distribution logic: 1) Bidder with highest offer gets all the shares they bid for, and then 2) if there are ties in $ bid price, assign shares to earlier bidder

For the above question, I feel like the solution I came up with is relatively simple but it seems to pass all edge cases I can think of. The only questionable situation I can think of is like

- Bid price and times are the same and there aren't enough shares for all bidders ie: bids = [[0,2,10,0], [1,2,10,0]] and totalShares = 2. I'm unclear if like 1 share should be given to each or userid 0 just gets both.

Does anyone see if my solution could be optimized in anyway?

```
def getUnallocatesUsers(bids, totalShares):
  s = 0
  for b in bids:
      s += b[1]  
  if totalShares >= s: return []  # no losers because enough shares to go around

  bids.sort(key = lambda x: (-x[2],x[3]))  # sort by highest bid, then timestamp for ties
  losers = []
  for b in bids:
    if totalShares <= 0: losers.append(b[0])
    else:
      totalShares -= b[1]
  return losers
```

Comment: Maybe try posting this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for better feedback

Comment: This [has been posted on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/247977). Please don't use it as a  reason to close this question as some users on Code Review will likely think it's off-topic. If this is off-topic here please use your standard close reasons. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution doesn't handle the round-robin part. If there are more than 1 bid for the same price, you'll need to give each user at least 1 share until and iterate over the users.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to the problem, the case: `bids = [[0,2,10,0], [1,2,10,0]]` should return `[]`. Because there's a tie, and each can be assigned one share.
I recommend the use of `heapq` and an extra array for dealing with tie.